# Update List with Another List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have List and I created a new copy from this List and Bind it into a Gridview
Where the user can update , delete and insert records.

What I want is when the user clicks on a button to update the List with the binded List.

How I can do this taking into consideration the following :

- Update only the Changed records.
- Insert news records into the list.
- delete records that don't exist in the binded List.

Comment: So let me get this straight. List A gets bound to a control and outputs List B. You then want to take List A, add all the new records from B, take away any records that don't exist in B and update any records that were changed in B... doesn't this mean that List A == List B???

Comment: Sorry If I didn't Explain properly basically ListB is copy from ListA , ListB is is the datasource of gridview , where the user edit,insert..etc , Save button Update the ListA records with the changes that happened in ListB

Comment: Why are you creating a copy of the list at all? Are you doing any checks on the new data?

Comment: Exactly, Is like a SpreadSheet , the user can add and edit records as much as he want but If he didn't like Changes , he simply doesn't click the Save button and the List remain unchanged .

Comment: I'm sensing you 're doing something completely unecessary there...

Comment: @Medo: If you always need to update the list, why don't work with one list??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty , You can say that List is a Category List for a website if the system admin manipulate the List through gridview the visitors will see the changes of every action while browsing the site , I want them to see it only when the admin click the save button more like Bulk Update/insert/delete

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not convinced what you're doing needs to be done, but here is a simple solution which should get more or less what you're looking for (I think).

```
for(int i = 0; i < myListB.Count; i++)
{
    //if items have been added to list B, they will be added to end of A
    if( i >= myListA.Count ) myListA.Add(myListB[i]);
    /* if item at index i in list A does not match item at index i 
     * in list B, assign item at index i in list B to index i in 
     * list A
     */
     else if( myListA[i] != myListB[i] ) myListA[i] = myListB[i];
}
```